# query in Vba using cdate function with variable

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba

Using the following query in microsoft access sql view works nice and easy with a hard coded date

> ```
> SELECT Salary.First, Salary.Last,FROM Salary, allowances
> WHERE Salary.PayThroughDate = CDate("2014-05-06") AND Salary.SSN = allowances.SSN
> ```

but embedding this query in Vba using a variable instead of a hard coded date is another business. It is just not working:

> ```
> Dim ddate As Variant
> Dim getDay As Integer
> Dim getMonth As Integer
> Dim getYear As Integer
> getDay = Day(Me.DTPicker2.Value)
> getMonth = Month(Me.DTPicker2.Value)
> getYear = Year(Me.DTPicker2.Value)
> ddate = getDay & "/" & getMonth & "/" & getYear
> ddate = Format(ddate, "dd/mm/yyyy")
>
> query1 = "SELECT Salary.First, Salary.Last FROM Salary, allowances WHERE Salary.PayThroughDate =  " & CDate(ddate) & " AND Salary.SSN =
> ```
>
> allowances.SSN

Any ideas in this Vba Sql mix? Am I missing single or double quotes?

Comment: Please note that tags stand alone.  That is, you can't combine multiple tags to create a single concept.  The tags `[microsoft]` and `[access]` together aren't the same thing as the single `[ms-access]` tag.  Always be sure to read the descriptions that appear when selecting tags!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you send the SQL directly to JET and not running it from the normal user-interface of MS Access, you will need to make the date-format in the American format. I have had this problem a lot long time ago, but solved it by using this function to format my date in to text, the way that JET expects it to be:

```
Function SQLDate(varDate As Date) As String
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Purpose    Formats a date in the american way so that it can be used in
'           SQL (by the JET-engine)
'Accepts    varDate - the date that should be converted to text
'Returns    The date converted to text, in american format with both the day and
'           the month using 2 characters.  (01 is january)
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
'Changelog
'HANY 20100407: Stopped using the FORMAT-function for the date-value, as I found some
'               cases where the format did not return the date as specified.
'---------------------------------------------------------------------------------------

    'SQLDate = "#" & Format$(varDate, "mm\/dd\/yyyy") & "#"
    SQLDate = "#" & Format(Month(varDate), "00") & "/" & Format(Day(varDate), "00") & "/" & Format(Year(varDate), "0000") & "#"
End Function
```

In your example above, you now add the date like this `& SQLDate(CDate(ddate)) &` instead of `& CDate(ddate) &`

Comment: In Access/VB6, numeric format is best: sqldate=double(vardate) that is fast and unambiguous, since it is the native Access form of dates. Unfortunatly, conversion to SQL Server form can cause unexpected results, so in general, standard date format is best for Access and Sql server: yyyy-mm-dd. Useing that format completely avoids "evil date guessing".

Answer (score -1):

The equivilant query is:

```
query1 = "SELECT Salary.First, Salary.Last 
FROM Salary, allowances 
WHERE (Salary.PayThroughDate =Cdate(" & ddate & ") )
AND (Salary.SSN = allowances.SSN)"
```

The problem you had is that when you constructed the sql string, the cdate value was converted into a string value first. It was just the same as

```
WHERE (Salary.PayThroughDate =" & format(ddate,"general date") & ")
```

If you do the cdate conversion later it works.  Another almost equivilant query is

```
...
WHERE Salary.PayThroughDate =#" & ddate & "#
...
```

Both Cdate and the # tags take a string date, and convert to a date type (using slightly different rules).  Since a date type is actually stored as the integer part of a double, you can also do:

```
WHERE Salary.PayThroughDate =cdbl(#" & ddate & "#)
```

or

```
WHERE Salary.PayThroughDate =clng(#" & ddate & "#)
```

or

```
WHERE Salary.PayThroughDate =" & clng(cdate(ddate) & "
```

--the number will be converted into a string to be part of the sql string, but numbers work correctly in SQL: they don't need to have # tags or conversion functions to make them work.

but you started out with a date value:

```
v =Me.DTPicker2.Value
```

so you can convert that directly to a number without converting it to a string first:

```
d = clng(Me.DTPicker2.Value)
...
WHERE (Salary.PayThroughDate = " & d & ")
```

which is the fastest and least error prone of handling dates in Access/VBA, but comes undone when you start working with SQL server, which stores dates differently.

Also, I see that you correctly used ISO date format when constructing your test example, but switched to American date format when constructing a string from the date value. That was a mistake. To avoid errors and 'evil date guessing' in SQL, you should stick to the ISO format:

```
v =Me.DTPicker2.Value
sdate = format(v,"yyyy-mm-dd")
```